# How to get full language id for locale in iOS

Tags: ios, localization, locale, nslocale

How to get full language id for locale in iOS in format that Apple itself described in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) as :

> [language designator]-[script designator]_[region designator]

The recomended way to get current language seems to be:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

but the return value is not very consistent it returns en for American English, en_GB for British english, zh-Hant for Traditional Chinese but zh_HK for Tranditional Chinese if region is set to Hong Kong.

The bigger task is that i have translations stored in files named [language]-[script] (for example zh-Hant & zh-Hans) and i would like to properly map zh_HK(which is in fact zh-Hant_HK) to zh-Hant translation file